# Custom models working with storeViews

Tags: magento2, module, model, store-view, store-id

I made a custom module that creates a model which can be associated to products. There are 2 tables:

- `Model` (for simplify, it only has an `id`, `name` and `img`)
- `ModelProduct` (`id`, `id_model`, `id_product`)

I have this, and it works fine for my purposes.

Now it has to be multilingual, in particular I only need that the name of the Model be in every storeView. So how can I do it?

The first thought is add another column in model `store_id` but then I will have to save the same association for every storeView, because the same Model translated for every storeView will have differents id.

So I didn't know how to do next, these solutions came to me:

- I can add another column on the Model like `model_id` and save the same if for every storeView, and in `ModelProduct` save that `model_id` instead of `id`.
- Add storeView on ModelProduct and add a row for every storeView with the same association.

But I don't know if there is a better way to do these kind of things. I think is a recurring problem, working with storeViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom EAV model so you can scope name to storeview.
Look that module as example of how to create custom EAV models in magento 2 https://github.com/ksz2013/m2-foggyline-office

Comment: Seems working with EAV solves my problem, but know I'm having some troubles making that custom model with EAV attributes. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174689/magento-2-custom-model-with-eav-attributes-put-is-not-working